# The limit when n approaches infinity of the subtraction of two sequences equals negative infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having trouble trying to prove the next:

\begin{align*}
  &\text{If } \lim_{{n \to \infty}} b_n = \infty \text{ and the sequence } a_n \text{ is bounded, then} \\
  &\lim_{{n \to \infty}} (a_n - b_n) = -\infty.
\end{align*}

The definition for \begin{align*}
  &\lim_{{n \to \infty}} (a_n - b_n) = -\infty.
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  &\forall M < 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}\text{ s.t }n > N\text{ , }a_n-b_n < M
\end{align*}

So far I've tried using definitions, but I can't get to prove it

I also have used that an is bound so: $\exists L \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $|a_n| \leq L$

So:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \ |a_n| \leq L \iff -L < a_n < L$$
$$ a_n - b_n < L - b_n $$
but I don´t really know what to do next, I have tried using:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty \Leftrightarrow \forall M > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ sucht hat if $n > N$, then $b_n > M$. but I don't know how to use it for the proof because here $M > 0$

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you write the definition of $\lim_{{n \to \infty}} (a_n - b_n) = -\infty$?

Comment: If $b_n>M$, then $L-b_n<L-M$. now you can make $M$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: $lim_{n \to \infty} b_n= \infty$ implies $lim_{n \to \infty} -b_n= -\infty$ and since $a_n$ is bounded, so $-k \leq lim_{n \to \infty} a_n \leq k$. Now add these two together and use algebra of limits.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \infty$, for any $M > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $b_n > M$.
$$
\text{Since } a_n \text{ is bounded, } \exists L \in \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, |a_n| \leq L.
$$
Choose $M' > L$. Then for $M'$ there exists $N'$ such that for all $n \geq N'$, $b_n > M'$.
Thus, for all $n \geq N'$, $a_n - b_n \leq L - b_n < -b_n$ and since $b_n > M'$, it follows that $-b_n < -M'$. Therefore, $a_n - b_n < -M'$.
Hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n - b_n) = -\infty.$

Comment: Note: This is what a formal proof would look like. But the intuition behind is hinted at by @AlanAbraham in the above comment